# How can i fetch only this Symbol column from my Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stockquotes

I have a Bhav Copy Dataframe which is I Downloaded from NSE website.
[image]

And In this Dataset I just wanna print Symbol Column.

```
print(bhav_copy['SYMBOL'])
```

but it is giving me this error,
[image]

Sorry, I don't know what to say about this column name series in which only the Symbol column stored in a different format and other column stores in a different format in Bhav Copy Dataframe.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it uses images of code and data

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Furthermore, I think you 'SYMBOL' column is actually your index. You could reset your index (`reset_index`) or print your index (`print(bhav_copy.index)`)

Comment: @Paul In my problem, there is no code, it's just a data frame which I can show through image, and next line I'm just print column which I have already written in code format. So how can I show this problem in code, please think practically?

Comment: I guess you haven't read the info of the links I commented.

Comment: @paul you wrote, "I’m voting to close this question because it uses images of code and data ". Can you please tell me where I'm showing you picture of my code? I'm just showing you my data frame image because it is hard for me to explain my problem, I'm not good at English so I tried to show my problem by image.

Comment: @Paul And If you think there is a better way of explain my problem, so why don't you just show me how to write it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240990/discussion-between-paul-and-krishna-gupta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KeyError` exception happened when there is a mistake in column name

Check your `SYMBOL` column name if it spelled correctly and be carful column name is **Case Sensitive**, you can check columns names in Dataframe by using:

```
bhav_copy.columns
```

It should be formatted like that to print specific column data from a Dataframe:

```
bhav_copy[["SYMBOL"]]
bhav_copy["SYMBOL"]
```

The single bracket version gives a Pandas Series, the double bracket version gives a Pandas DataFrame.

For more info on this topic check this [reference](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-select-columns).

Comment: @oghili Thank you. for your help.

Comment: @KrishnaGupta check my updated solution.

Answer (score 0):

reset_index technique worked for me.

```
bhav_copy.reset_index(inplace = True)
bhav_copy['SYMBOL']
```

Comment: Actually the problem not in resetting index, it's in your column name because it's case sensitive so when you write above `SYMBOL` name in capital case it gives you `KeyError` exception.

Comment: @Oghli It was just my typing mistake brother.

Comment: No problem be carful to the case of column name in the future. wish you the best.